# Finding linear and angular speeds

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, rotations

(b) A wheel of radius 5 in. is rotating 45°/sec. What is the linear speed v, the angular speed in RPM and the angular speed in rad/sec?
So for this one I thought the linear speed (v)= 5(pi/2) because it is asking for rad/sec so 45 degrees in pi/2. But it is wrong..

(c) You are standing on the equator of the earth (radius 3960 miles). What is your linear (mph) and angular speed (rad/hr)? 
So I dont know how to even get the answer. I know the equation v (linear speed) = w(omega) *radius is important, but I dont know how to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$45^\circ/sec=\frac{\pi}{4} rad/sec$
So, angular speed $\omega=\frac{\pi}{4}$ rad/sec=$15\pi$ rad/min = $7.5$ RPM (since $2\pi =$ one revolution)

linear speed = $\omega * r = \frac{\pi}{4}(5)$ in/sec

you should be able to do part (c) now.